# Audio manager for 3d position audio on a per-application basis (Windows)

Tags: windows, audio

I just recently purchased some headphones and would like to emulate the positions of desktop speakers on a per-application basis.

Ideally, the software would be similar to the Windows 7 Volume Mixer but also allow me to control the 3d position of each application in addition to the volume as well.

**So how about it? Are there any Windows applications/audio drivers designed to mix audio in a 3d space on a per-application basis?**

---

#### Context:

It might seem weird that I would want to do this, but I think I have a good use case. I frequently talk to others in voip applications (Skype, Teamspeak, Mumble, Ventrillo, Google Hangouts, etc.) and previously had only that application's audio come over the headphones while the system audio was routed through my desktop speakers. My new headphones do a pretty good job at blocking out the desktop speakers and I find mixing all of the application audio together to be confusing to the ears.

I want to separate these things and essentially set the audio position for normal applications to be in front of me, much like my desktop speakers were. Then, I'll set the communication audio to be "in my head" so-to-speak.